# jQuery stopping bold,underline and other events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RGmNz/6/

And have tried to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> etc...

```
  $("iframe").contents().find("body").keydown(function(a,b){

        if(a.which ==32 && a.ctrlKey){
            a.preventDefault(); 
           }
    });
})
```

But it still bolds the text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you make two changes: (1) Use the right keycode for b, i.e., 66 rather than 32, and (2) add a call to `.stopPropagation()`:

```
if (a.which == 66 && a.ctrlKey) {
    a.preventDefault();
    a.stopPropagation();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RGmNz/7/

Or you can `return false` which is the equivalent of both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is `return false;` With keycode stuff i've always found that when trying to disable certain events, you simply need to return false and stop absolutely everything from happening. (It will do preventDefault & stopPropogation for you)

Also just noticed this: [info on keycode #'s](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```
    // you want to do 66 (B)
    // with && since you're looking for both events simultaneously

    if (a.which === 66 && a.ctrlKey) {  
       return false;
    }
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KnY9A/1/)